# "Апрель" и "апрель месяц"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Является ли литературным оборот "апрель месяц"? И для чего вообще часто к названию добавляют слово "месяц"? Неужели и так не ясно?)))

Comment: "В юном **месяце апреле** в старом парке тает снег..."

Comment: Хочется напомнить, что "апрель месяц" - это типичный плеоназм, такой же как "первая премьера, сто рублей денег, передовой авангард" и т.д. Употребление их крайне нежелательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если и является, то в той же мере, сколько и сам канцелярит. Я бы рекомендовал этого оборота всячески избегать хотя бы вне официальных бумаг. Что же касается документов, то там это уже сложно сделать, настолько въелось это в сознание наших бюрократов.

Comment: Есть бесчисленные примеры (помноженные на двенадцать) употребления такого оборота в первую очередь в художественной литературе.

Answer (score 2):

Это штамп официально-делового стиля - *12 числа апреля месяца 2013 года...*

Связан этот штамп, по всей видимости с бланками, где мелким шрифтом напечатано, что должно быть в данной графе.

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что «канцелярит»  придуман юристами и придуман не для пустословия / краснобайства / позерства / понтов, а например, с целью унификации формулировок официальных писем, что позволяет достигать максимальной точности перевода корреспонденции с одного языка на другой (и обратно). Например, слова Януарий или Юлий только в русском языке (преимущественно) употребляются в качестве наименования месяцев и для  точного понимания смысла официального документа гражданами иных стран дополнение «месяц» не выглядит лишним. 
Оно не будет лишним и в случае употребления не очень распространенных наименований типа: «липень», «травень», «лютень».

Не стоит искать отголосков «канцелярита» в хороших стихах или художественной прозе. Там словосочетание «месяц май» может заменять (пусть давно и единожды, но) уже использованное - «майская пора».

Была уж майская пора, 
И солнце жаркими лучами
Палило пышный град Петра…
[Н. П. Огарев. Юмор. Часть вторая (1840-1841)]

Прошло три года. Была прелестная степная майская пора... [Г. П. Данилевский. Беглые в Новороссии (1862)]

Answer (score 0):

В академическом справочнике Лопатина в параграфе о дефисном (слитном, раздельном) написании говорится:

> § 122. Следующие сочетания пишутся раздельно.

...

> 5. Сочетания типа *январь месяц*, *в марте месяце*.

Там ничего не сказано ни про недопустимость такого употребления, ни про канцелярит.