# Корректность выражения "в декабре месяце"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли употреблять сочетание "в декабре месяце" и насколько корректно такое употребление? Наткнулся в интернете на ресурсе "Екатеринбург говорит правильно" на сведения о том, что выражение паразитическое и одно слово дублирует смысл другого. С другой стороны, нашёл у Л. Н. Толстого произведение "Севастополь в декабре месяце". Допустимо ли написание сочетания через дефис?

Comment: Выражение, считаю, не паразитическое, наоборот, оно придаёт выразительность словам. То есть по смыслу то же самое, но звучит красивее. Конечно, это не значит, что говорит надо так постоянно. Нет, иногда, в определённом настроении. Через дефис писать не надо.

Comment: Уже было об этом: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18380/%d0%90%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%86/440925#440925. Повторюсь, что в предыдущем комментарии моё мнение, я могу ошибаться, может оно и измениться.

Answer (score 1):

В современном языке это *формальное* выражение, канцеляризм. В деловой речи и документообороте оно добавляет строгости указанию на месяц (как на отчётный период и т. п.; в устной речи /докладе/ нельзя спутать напр. с акционерным обществом "Декабрь") - заинтересованные люди, *обратив внимание* на формальный стиль, могут проверить, не подразумевается ли конкретный месяц напр. строго с первого по последнее число, и т. д.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&start=15